# CocoaPods connection fail

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I'm trying to get my swift Xcode project to connect with Firebase, but I'm getting an error. I followed the exact steps provided in `add Firebase to your iOS app` step, and it's saying I have Thread 1: signal SIGABRT (terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException). I tried multiple times just to remove pods from the directory/project and start over but I feel like I'm removing the pods wrong. Is there a way I can completely remove all pods/configurations created to the projects?

podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SimonGame' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SimonGame
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end
```

app delegate:

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

Comment: There could be 100 different things causing the issue. If the steps in the getting started guide are followed accurately, they work, so that indicates a step was missed or something is out of order. The first thing to do is to include your podfile in your question as well as your app delegate setup code as well. Include as text please, no links or images. Ensure you are starting the project using the *.xcworkspace* file and for working with podfiles, take a look at the Cocoapods app - it's a nice UI front end. It also has a simple *Remove Podfile from project* option

Comment: i've added  podfile and appdelegate in my question

Comment: Is this a Real Time Database app or a Firestore app? If it's RTDB, you may have omitted `pod 'Firebase/Database'` in your podfile. If it's Firestore, note that your app delegate does not match what's in the [Firestore Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize) or the [Example App Delegate](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-ios/blob/cb5ed683b5e447d575792904c0971827060d729f/firestore/swift/firestore-smoketest/AppDelegate.swift#L31-L33) which may or may not have an impact but it's a good place to start. Try cocoapods.app to remove podfiles and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pod deintegrate` to completely remove pods from your project but if Firebase is causing the issue, it better that you remove Firebase from your pods and run `pod install` again. See if the issue still persists. It would be better if you could paste the crash backtrace here to find out the real cause of crash.

Comment: I did pod reintegrate and it says  "The workspace referencing the Pods project still remains." What should I delete in Xcode project?

Comment: You can delete the pods folder in your project main directory and run `pod deintegrate` again

Comment: please post the crash backtrace

Comment: did you add the GoogleService-Info.plist file @JiwooLee

Answer (score -1):

try this remove the # sign from platform :ios, '9.0'

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SimonGame' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SimonGame
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end
```